# Plotly add_trace changes y_axis range & spacing - Python

Tags: python, plot, plotly, plotly-python

I have run into this issue twice recently when creating plots with two traces that are plotted on the same y-axis. It seems that adding a second trace using the same y-axis causes the y-axis to add empty space above and below. I have tried setting the yaxes range, but to no avail.

I first created the plot using only a Bar trace, and everything looked great (see below).

[image: Plot with only 1 trace]

When I added the scatter trace, the y-axis then added empty space above and below (as if the y-axis was going from first-y-axis-label - 5 to last-y-axis-label + 5).

[image: Plot with 2 traces & wonky y-axis]

I'm not sure why adding this second trace causes this change in the y-axis as they both use the same data column. When I've tried things like `fig.update_yaxes(range=['Mar 15, 2021: #1','Aug 26, 2021: #87'])` or `fig.update_yaxes(range=[0,len(df)])` it doesn't change anything.

This is my code for the plot. I removed the code that adds the vrects and % annotations because those have no impact on the problem and are just a bunch of extra code.

I'd really appreciate any help!

```
segs = px.bar(quantdf, 
              x='cadence', 
              y='label', 
              orientation='h',
             labels={'cadence':'Avg. Cadence', 'label':'Ride'})

segs.update_traces(marker_color='#4c4c4c', opacity=.9)

segs.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=quantdf.cadence,
                         y=quantdf.label,
                         mode='markers',
                         marker_size=8,
                         marker_color="#4c4c4c",
                         showlegend=False,
                         hovertemplate="Ride = %{y}<br>" + "Avg. Cadence" + "= %{x}<extra></extra>"))

segs.update_layout(template=peloton_plot_template,
                  height=1600,
                  bargap=.9,
                  title=dict(font_size=22,
                             x=0.05,
                             y=.99,
                             yref='container',
                             text=f"<b>Avg. Cadence of my Peloton cycling rides</b>"))

segs.update_yaxes(autorange='reversed',
                 dtick=1,
                 type='category',
                 title='')

segs.update_xaxes(range=[round(quantdf.cadence.min()-10, 10), quantdf.cadence.max() + 5],
                 showgrid=False)
```

Comment: if you just plot the scatter,  the scatter has this padding.  https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1775 can't see anyway to prevent it